# Change img src on page reload by class name

Tags: javascript, src

I want to change the image `src` in my header with the class name `custom-logo` to load one of those images in my array on a page reload. This doesn't seem to be working:

```
var images = [
  'Logo-1.jpg',
  'Logo-2.jpg',
  'Logo-3.jpg',
  'Logo-4.jpg'
]

var which = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var img = document.getElementByClassName('custom-logo');
img.src = images[which];
```

Comment: `img` will be a collection of elements. use `img[0].src = ...`, assuming you only have one `.custom-logo` element

Comment: Should be `getElementsByClassName` - Elements

Comment: @Pete I always miss that one :)